# Explaining this particular version of the Implicit Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, intuition

I understand the general 'word' definitions of the Implicit Function Theorem and the simple examples such as the one on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#First_example) but the version of the Implicit Function theorem given in our lecture notes seems pretty obscure (or perhaps I am just missing something). Here it is.

> Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^p$ be open and $f:D \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuously differentiable. Further assume $$f(\bar{x},\bar{\lambda}) = 0 \, \, \,  \mathrm{and} \, \, \,  \det f_1'(\bar{x},\bar{\lambda})\neq 0.$$ Then there is a neighbourhood $N$ of $\bar{\lambda}$ and a uniquely determined continuously differentiable mapping $$\phi : N \to \mathbb{R}^m \quad N \subset \mathbb{R}^p$$ such that for all $\lambda \in N$ $$f(\phi(\lambda), \lambda) = 0.$$

Can someone please try and explain this particular formulation of the Implicit Function Theorem in a different way? Thanks!

Comment: Could you expand on what you don't understand?

Comment: Perhaps this might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128269/intuitive-understanding-about-the-implicit-function-theorem/128271#128271

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I think that in the statement of the theorem $n=m$; in the following I will assume so. $f$ is a function depending on $m+p$ variables: ($x_1,\dots,x_m,\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_p)$. $f$ is a vector valued function taking values in $\mathbb{R}^m$; let $f_1,\dots,f_m$ be its components. We are given a system of $m$ equations in $m+p$ unknowns:
$$\begin{align*}
f_1(x_1,\dots,x_m,\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_p)&=0,\\
f_2(x_1,\dots,x_m,\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_p)&=0,\\
\dots\dots\dots\qquad&=0,\\
f_m(x_1,\dots,x_m,\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_p)&=0,\\
\end{align*}$$
Our goal is to solve for $x_1,\dots,x_m$ in terms of $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_p$. The implicit function theorem gives sufficient conditions for this to be possible. What are these conditions?

1. There exists at least one solution. In mathematical notation, this is written as: there exists $(\bar x,\bar\lambda)\in D$ such that $f(\bar x,\bar\lambda)=0$.
2. A certain *non-degeneracy* condition is satisfied. In this case it is
   $$
   \frac{\partial(f_1,\dots,f_m)}{\partial(x_1,\dots,x_m)}(\bar x,\bar\lambda)=
   \det\,\begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}(\bar x,\bar\lambda)&\dots&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_m}(\bar x,\bar\lambda)\\
   \dots&\dots&\dots\\
   \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1}(\bar x,\bar\lambda)&\dots&\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_m}(\bar x,\bar\lambda)\\
   \end{pmatrix}\ne0.
   $$

If they are satisfied, the theorem guarantees the existence of $C^1$ functions $x_k=\phi_k(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_p)$, $1\le k\le m$, solving the equation.

The theorem is called the implicit function theorem because the system of equations defines implicitely $x_1,\dots,x_m$ as functions of $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_p$.